# How to compute this integral on contour

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How to compute this following integral?

$$\int \limits_{C}^{}\frac{e^{az^2}\,dz}{z^4+1}$$

Given $ a>0$  and  $C:=\{z: |z+1| = 1\}$ is positively oriented.

Where should I start? What would $f(z)$ be in $Res(f(z),z)$ with $e^{az^2}$?

Comment: Do you really want $x^4+1$ in the denominator? (Shouldn't it be $z^4+1$?)

Comment: @mrf sorry that's my typo

Comment: First, what are the singularities of the integrand? Second, which of these are inside $C?$